# Is it possible to fork/convert an ERC20 smart contract token to BSC?

Tags: solidity

I am interested in forking an ERC20 token smart contract to BSC token (same functionality but in a different network) would that be possible?
More specifically I am looking for converting the following project?

https://github.com/reflectfinance/reflect-contracts/blob/main/contracts/REFLECT.sol

Answer (score 1):

BSC is fully compatible with EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine).

So, you can deploy a smart contract to both BSC and Ethereum blockchain without any changes.